# In an Excel sheet, how can I validate a column to accept only numbers and reject dates? (ISNUMBER is not working)

Tags: node.js, excel, typescript, xlsx-populate

I have a column named 'quantity' where the user should only input a number

```
sheet.range(`D2:D${allItems.length + 1}`).dataValidation({
        type: 'whole',
        operator: 'greaterThan',
        formula1: '0',
        showErrorMessage: true,
        errorTitle: 'Invalid Quantity',
        error: 'Please enter a valid quantity.',
        errorStyle: 'stop',
        errorAlert: 'warning',
      });
```

This function works correctly, but during testing, when I input '1-2', it converts it into a date and accepts it, which is a significant issue. I attempted to use ISNUMBER(), but it didn't work.

Note. The ISNUMBER function allows any numeric values in validated cells, including integers, decimals, fractions as well as dates and times, which are also numbers in terms of Excel.

Comment: What's the expected evaluation of `1-2`? Is it an arithmetic expression equal to -1 or is it a range from 1 to 2?

Comment: @jsheeran while attempting to input '1-2' in the quantity column cell, it was inadvertently converted to '2-Jan'.

Comment: @jsheeran I want to validate all the cells in the quantity column to only accept numbers, rejecting dates and times.

Comment: Understood, but when a user is entering that value in that cell what would they be expecting to happen? If a cell expects a number and a user enters "1-2" I'd consider that an input error.

Comment: @jsheeran return an error message

Comment: @jsheeran It leads to an error in all cells, including when inputting a number :       sheet.range(`D2:D${allItems.length + 1}`).dataValidation({
        type: 'whole',
        operator: 'between',
        minimumValue: 0,
        maximumValue: 99999,
        showErrorMessage: true,
        errorTitle: 'Invalid Quantity',
        error: 'Please enter a whole number between 0 and 99999.',
        errorStyle: 'stop',
        errorAlert: 'warning',
      });

Comment: This is a difficult one, as Excel retains dates as numbers. You could try to force use of a decimal point by using a custom formula in the validation, like this: =NOT(ISERROR(FIND(".",A1)))

Comment: i can suggest a workaround if the numbers you deal with are not too big (say, less than 5 digits).

Comment: @SelloBello106 If your allowable range is `0..99999`, and you want to use data validation, you may be able to set the format of the cell/column to `Text` before entering the data and then check each character for being a digit.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Is there any implementation available?

Comment: @SelloBello106 I'm not familiar with your tools (except, of course, for Excel) or workflow, but I'd imagine you'd have to develop this yourself. Even in Excel, you'd have to ensure the column was set to `Text` format, or write some VBA event-triggered macros.